# Show nav menu after scrolling up 50px

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, offset

I want to show a sticky menu nav when scrolling up while also having a delay before showing the nav menu. I can do this with animate and opacity, but it's not as effective.

I tried to show the nav menu when scrolling up 50px from the current position, but it didn't work.

Here's the script:

```
var previousScroll = 0,
    headerOrgOffset = $('#header').height();

$('#header-wrap').height($('#header').height());

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll > headerOrgOffset) {
        if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
            $('#header-wrap').slideUp();
        } else {
            $('#header-wrap').slideDown();
        }
    } 
    previousScroll = currentScroll;
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dXQbk/410/)

Note: I saw this feature in the script for Headroom.js

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current setup only accounts for scrolls that are greater than `headerOrgOffset`. If you want the slide down to happen, you need to account for cases where the scroll is less than `headerOrgOffset`. Since you also want a 50px buffer, I've added a -50 in the else statement.

```
var previousScroll = 0,
        savedScroll = 0,
    headerOrgOffset = $('#header').height();

$('#header-wrap').height($('#header').height());

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll > headerOrgOffset) {
        if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
            $('#header-wrap').slideUp();
            reappearScroll = currentScroll - 50;
        } else {
            if (currentScroll < reappearScroll) {
                $('#header-wrap').slideDown();
            }
        }
    } 
    previousScroll = currentScroll;
});
```

Comment: Hi @Imylor... I've updated the code. Please let me know if it's what you wanted.

Comment: Hello Josepth, first thanks for your help, the code not work like I want, I whant to show nav menu when scroll up just after 50px from current position when scroll up, like this example:  http://jsfiddle.net/fKqMN/23/  if you scroll to bottom and then scroll up, wait a seconds and see  show nav.  that example work with animate and opacity, but I want to do different. like my question said.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to show the nav menu when you scroll up 50px anywhere in the browser. Should the navbar appear when they're 50px from the top of the page, or if they scroll up 50px even if they're at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Show nav menu when scroll up just after 50px from current position(anywhere) when scroll up.

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification I wasn't sure. I've readjusted the code. If this is what you want please accept the answer!