# When the user scrolls up, show the navbar — but not immediately. How to?

Tags: javascript

I would like to improve an existing code that allows me to show the navbar after the user scrolls upwards, but with a delay of XXX Px scrolling Upwards. How can I integrate this Pixel-Amount-Delay in my function?

I hope someone can help me to implement this.

```
/* When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */

var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;

    if (
        prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos
    ) {
        document.getElementById("navi").style.bottom = "0";

    } else {
        document.getElementById("navi").style.bottom = "-30vh";

    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

Right now, the navbar appears immediately when scrolling upwards.

Comment: My Question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078005/show-nav-menu-after-scrolling-up-50px

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just put a condition for pixels depending on how much you need it.

```
// When the user scrolls down 30px from the top of the document, slide down the navbar
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 30 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 30) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
   document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
 }
}
```